# "Extracting command line tools for github" on every launch on Github Desktop App

Tags: github, github-for-windows

On every launch of Github Desktop app, i see a screen that says

> Please Wait,
>    Extracting command line tools for github,  This might take
>   a minute or two

and it really takes almost 1 minute.
Is it normal that this happens on every launch of the program or is there something wrong?

Comment: Hey, did you get a solution for this. I am getting a similar problem. Github stuck on "Please Wait" for an hour. Even after restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

Since June 2016, a new version of GitHub Desktop has been rewritten/released ([Sep 2017](https://blog.github.com/2017-09-19-announcing-github-desktop-1-0/): based on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)).

You [won't find an `Extracting command line...` message in the code anymore](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/search?q=extracting&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93).
It relies on the [system Git it will detect](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/commit/abefbc03e46de8d13b100abd7e8e562fafcf961d).

I haven't seen any issue when starting the new GitHub Desktop application.